# iOS 16 View Modifier not consistent across List headers

Tags: swiftui, viewmodifier, ios16

Since iOS changed `List` to use `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView`, all my `Section` headers have taken on the background colors of my list cells.

I use a `ThemedList` to color my lists throughout the app:

```
struct ThemedList<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            content()
                .listRowBackground(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Simply replacing `List` with `ThemedList` throughout my app worked fine in `iOS 15`:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ThemedList {
            Section("Header") {
                Text("Row")
                Text("Row")
                Text("Row")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now on `iOS 16` it looks like this:

[image]

Ok, this should be a simple fix. Ive created a `ThemedSection` that makes the background `.clear`:

```
struct ThemedSection<Header, Content, Footer> {
    @ViewBuilder var header: () -> Header
    @ViewBuilder var footer: () -> Footer
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
}
extension ThemedSection : View where Header : View, Content : View, Footer : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            content()
        } header: {
            header()
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        } footer: {
            footer()
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
    }
}
```

and initialisers that mimic those of `Section`

```
extension ThemedSection where Header == Text, Content : View, Footer == EmptyView {
    
    init<S>(_ title: S, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) where S : StringProtocol {
        
        self.content = content
        self.header = { Text(title) }
        self.footer = { EmptyView() }
    }
}
```

Replacing all `Section` with `ThemedSection` in my app:

```
struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ThemedList {
            ThemedSection("Header") {
                Text("Row")
                Text("Row")
                Text("Row")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now the big problem. Not all of my `ThemedSection`'s show the clear header.

If I add my view to a `NavigationView` on it's own, it's still fine. If I add a second view to be the current detail view on iPad, then my list section no longer works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            Text("iPad selected initial view") // Remove line for headers to appear clear
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ThemedList {
            ThemedSection("Header") {
                Text("Row")
                Text("Row")
                Text("Row")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I can even have the same view as my master and detail in the navigation and the detail works but the master doesn't.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            SidebarView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can someone explain what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Full code [gist](https://gist.github.com/ddaddy/010054740df06ecdfab5bc75abf1b54b)

Comment: Set the `.listStyle` so you have consistency

Comment: Wow, that worked. But why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `.listStyle` so you have consistency

Because Apple can decide what `.listStyle` is best, it has changed with every version of SwiftUI for different settings.

If you set it, then it takes your preference not Apple's preference for the circumstance.

The photos you show are `.plain` for the sidebar and `.grouped` for the detail.

Comment: `.plain` `.grouped` & `.insetGrouped` work, but `.sidebar` doesn't. Why would that be?

Comment: @Darren probably more limitations for Sidebar it doesn't do much in certain situations. Apple doesn't provide much on it.